# is there a way to modify arguments before NSApplicationMain?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I would like to modify the command line arguments, in particular, add or modify the "-AppleLanguages" (which automagically picked up by the MacOS) so that my app uses different language settings according to some locale arguments specified by user.

For example, "myApp -uselocale es_es" will use Spanish for my UI, instead of the default system language.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    // I want to modify arguments before it runs!
    NSApplicationMain(argc,  (const char **) argv);
    return 0;
}
```

It is said no effect seen if you modify argv in main before calling NSApplicationMain, as it get arguments from NSProcessInfo.

Therefore one needs to change NSProcessInfo.arguments.
I found something here: http://www.taffysoft.com/pages/20060612-01.html. 
However when I added that code to my main.m, it generates link error: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: “_OBJC_IVAR_$_NSProcessInfo.arguments”.

Is there any way to achieve this without relaunching my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a way to modify the arguments, but you can achieve your ultimate goal by simply setting a value for the AppleLanguages default in your app's preferences. If you do it early enough, it will be effective for that launch. For example:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@[@"zh-Hant-TW"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

Note that the object is an array, not just a string.

Comment: Thanks! Are there any way to effectively modify arguments at all? Also I assume the change of UserDefaults will only affect the calling application?

Comment: Yes, it only affects the calling app. I haven't really looked into what's possible as far as modifying the arguments. There are a lot of layers that you *might* care about: the original data that the kernel and C library set up, the values passed along to `NSApplicationMain()`, the `NSProcessInfo` dictionary, the Arguments domain of `NSUserDefaults`, etc. I suspect you can use `_NSGetArgv()` and `_NSGetArgc()` from <crt_externs.h> to modify the first and thus all of the rest.

Comment: I noticed after the change of NSUserDefaults as above, it writes to the defaults of myApp and can be verified by command line like: `defaults read com.me.myApp`. However, if I modify the language setting by command line, for example: `defaults write com.me.myApp AppleLanguages "(zh-cn)"`, the value does change in the result of `defaults read`, but it does not take effect when I launch myApp, seems it still uses the previous language settings. In other words, I can only change the behavior by launching myApp with new arguments, but not by using the `defaults` command. I wonder what's going on

Comment: I assume you have not yet modified your app to write the setting on launch, right? I'm not sure why it's not working, but I don't think "zh-cn" is correct. When I add various Chinese languages to System Preferences and read the global setting, I see zh-Hans* and zh-Hant*, not zh-cn.

Comment: Before launching my app, I modify it with `default write`, then My code won't overwrite the setting because no language specified in command line. strangely, the setting rolls back to the previous one used (seen in `default read`) and my app also uses the previous language.  BTW, it seems MacOS is quite permissive on locale strings: zh-cn, zh_cn, zh-CN etc. all work as well as zh-Hans etc.